# How to oprimize RXJS event?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is an RxJS event that emits when shift + w pressed.

```
fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    filter((e: any) => e.shiftKey && e.code === KeyCode.KeyW),
    takeUntil(this.takeUntil$)
// make does easy calculations
).subscribe(() => make());
```

This code makes the page freeze. How to improve it?

Comment: What does `make()` do?

Comment: it makes easy calculations

Comment: Did you try doing anything else other than make() in subscription? Also, what is takeUntil$?

Comment: You can use `fromEvent(document, 'keydown.shift.w')`. NOTE: If you want another approach to make keyboard short cut take a look to [this Netanel Basal's entry](https://netbasal.com/diy-keyboard-shortcuts-in-your-angular-application-4704734547a2). NOTE2: I don't know if this solve your problem.

Comment: @Eliseo, does this syntax actually work: `keydown.shfit.b` ?  I tried it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nrymzc?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts) with no luck.

Comment: The syntax works with angular event bindings `(document:keydown.shift.b)="..."` just fine.  Maybe that's what you were thinking of? [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt1z8j?file=src%2Fmain.ts&devtoolsHeight=60)

Comment: Can you post the browser console errors (reach via F12)?

Comment: Usually commands like this are bound to keyup

Comment: @BizzyBob, sorry, you can not use fromEvent to capture the keys, the only way is using HostListener, using a div or using renderer2. I added an answer with the three options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementary my comment (apologies to indicate we can do it using fromEvent).

There are three ways to "capture" the keys

1. using HostListener, e.g.

   ```
   @HostListener('document:keydown.shift.b') doSomething(){
       console.log("you click shift.b")
   }
   ```
2. using in a div

   ```
   <div (document:keydown.shift.b)="doSomething()"></div>
   ```
3. using renderer2

   ```
     listenerFn: () => void;
     constructor(private renderer:Renderer2){}
     ngOnInit()
     {
       this.listenerFn=this.renderer.listen(document, 'keydown.shift.b', ()=>{
         console.log("shift b")
       })
     }
     ngOnDestroy()
     {
       this.listenerFn && this.listenerFn();
     }
   ```